# How To Upload Multiple Image from Android to NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upload, port

I recently saw a tutorial to upload some photos from here [https://aguacatelang.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/android-multipart-upload-to-node-js/][1]

I've just learned nodejs and less understanding of the structure of programming languages, I found a mistake like this :

```
home/je/Documents/BE/UploadFoto/app.js:12
var db = new Db('photos', new dbServer('localhost', dbConnection.'27017', {}))
                                                                 ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

this is original source code :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

var fs = require('fs');
var im = require('imagemagick');

var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var dbServer = require('mongodb').Server;
var dbConnection = require('mongodb').Connection;

var db = new Db('photos', new dbServer('localhost', dbConnection.'DEFAULT_PORT', {}));
db.open(function(err, db){});

app.use(express.bodyParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(
        '<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
        '<input type="file" name="source">'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
        '</form>'
    );
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log("Received file:\n" + JSON.stringify(req.files));

    var photoDir = __dirname+"/photos/";
    var thumbnailsDir = __dirname+"/photos/thumbnails/";
    var photoName = req.files.source.name;

    fs.rename(
        req.files.source.path,
        photoDir+photoName,
        function(err){
            if(err != null){
                console.log(err)
                res.send({error:"Server Writting No Good"});
            } else {
                im.resize(
                    {
                        srcData:fs.readFileSync(photoDir+photoName, 'binary'),
                        width:256
                    }, 
                    function(err, stdout, stderr){
                        if(err != null){
                            console.log('stdout : '+stdout)

                            res.send({error:"Resizeing No Good"});
                        } else {
                            //console.log('ELSE stdout : '+stdout)
                            fs.writeFileSync(thumbnailsDir+"thumb_"+photoName, stdout, 'binary');
                            res.send("Ok");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
});

app.get('/info', function(req, res){
    console.log(__dirname);
    res.send("ok");
});

app.listen(8000);
console.log('connected to localhost....')
```

I switched  DEFAULT_PORT to 27017 because in my PC the port that is used mongodb:localhost/27017. May someone help me? thanks

Comment: What version of express are you using? As you can see here http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#core-changes the structure on Express 4.x changed and BodyParser is no longer part of express. It needs to be added separately..

Answer (score 2):

[BodyParser no longer supports parsing multypart requests](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). You should try using one of these modules.

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#examples).
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty).
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#readme).
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme).

Here is a simple example using multiparty:

```
 var multipart = require('multiparty');

 app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

    var form = new multipart.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {   
       console.log(files);//list all files uploaded 
       //put in here all the logic applied to your files.        
  }); 
  return;
});
```

Or you can use it as a middleware, like this:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

app.use(multipart());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.files);//list all files uploaded
     // apply all logic here
});
```

Comment: What do you meen by saying source code? Source code of what?

Comment: how can you handle multiple images or files in multer ? any idea @ Yaki?

Answer (score 0):

I am sending files like Audios,Images and videos etc from Android Using Retrofit  ,At server side i am using node.js .

on btnUpload click i am uploading my files to server .

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(MusicActivity.this, ""+ commonAdapter.getSelectedItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String fileUri=null;
                File file=null;
                RequestBody requestFile=null;
                MultipartBody.Part part=null;
                ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);


                for(int i=0;i<commonAdapter.getSelectedItems().size();i++)
                {
                    fileUri = commonAdapter.getSelectedItems().get(i);

                    file = new File(fileUri);

                    requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(fileUri), file);

      //music name must be same as music at node.js , 
      //if its different then it will not worked.
                    part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("music", file.getName(), requestFile);

                    Call<UploadObject> myResponseCall = apiService.uploadMusic(part);
                    myResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UploadObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<UploadObject> call, Response<UploadObject> response) {
                            Log.d("kkkk","ok response");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<UploadObject> call, Throwable t) {
                            // Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Error Occured ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("kkkk","on failed");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

My ApiInterface for Retrofit

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("api/uploadImage")
    Call<UploadObject> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    @Multipart
    @POST("api/uploadVideo")
    Call<UploadObject> uploadVideo(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    @Multipart
    @POST("api/uploadMusic")
    Call<UploadObject> uploadMusic(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

Its my getSelectedItem :- which return selected Items

```
 public ArrayList<String> getSelectedItems()
    {
        return selectedItems;
    }
```

At Node.js I am using multer

```
var express = require('express')
//const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express()

// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {

    var tmp_path = req.file.path;

    var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname;

    /** A better way to copy the uploaded file. **/
    var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
    src.pipe(dest);
    src.on('end', function() { console.log('complete') });
    src.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error'); });
    fs.unlink(tmp_path);
});

app.post('/api/uploadVideo', upload.single('video'), function (req, res, next) {

    var tmp_path = req.file.path;

    var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname;

    /** A better way to copy the uploaded file. **/
    var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
    src.pipe(dest);
    src.on('end', function() { console.log('complete') });
    src.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error'); });
    fs.unlink(tmp_path);
});

app.post('/api/uploadMusic', upload.single('music'), function (req, res, next) {
    var tmp_path = req.file.path;

    var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname;

    /** A better way to copy the uploaded file. **/
    var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
    src.pipe(dest);
    src.on('end', function() { console.log('complete') });
    src.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error'); });
    fs.unlink(tmp_path);
});

app.listen(8080,(res,err)=>{
  if(err)
    console.log('error occured while connecting port');
  else
    console.log('Server is Up');
});
```

I hope its help You!